# Обрезать строку начиная с символа

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Добрый день. Есть селект, возвращает строку:

```
select distinct short_name from equipment_type
```

Результаты вывода разные:

```
ГП
ГА
ГП; модель 25
```

В последнем результате мне для вывода не нужно *; модель 25*, только "ГП".
Как записать селект для отсечения символа ';' и последующих после него? substr не дает нужного результата.

Comment: А для показанного примера - должны вернуться 2 записи (DISTINCT после обрезки) или 3 (DISTINCT, потом обрезка, на выходе дубликат)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ самостоятельно - работает необходимым образом:

```
substr(ltrim(short_name), 1, instr(ltrim(short_name)||';', ';')-1)
```

Большое спасибо за участие!

Comment: Возможно ltrim в вашем случае лишние. И еще можно посмотреть в сторону regexp_substr

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(short_name, '[^;]+') short_name
FROM equipment_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что без `case` не обойтись:

```
select distinct 
           case instr(short_name, ';')
             when 0 then
               short_name
             else
               substr(short_name, 1, instr(short_name, ';') - 1)
           end as short_name

from equipment_type
```

PS: Вообще это больше похоже на проблему с архитектурой, отсюда и костыли